# C# Beginner Question about UserInput in a Method

Tags: c#, parsing, methods, member

I'm new to Programming and trying to do an first Program.

I want to use a Method for the User input to change Variables from the Main function.
But i get the Error: "Member 'float.Parse(string)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference"

Here's my Code

```
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {   float salary = 0;
        float rentalFee;
        float powerCosts;
        float gez;
        bool gezMonth;
        float insurence;
        bool insurenceMonth;
        userOutput("Geben sie einen Wert für ihr Gehalt ein");
        salary = UserInput(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine(salary);
        
    }
    private static float UserInput(string usrInput)
    {   
        float input= 0;
        input.Parse(usrInput);
        return input;
    }
```

i googled the error but i don't really understand the answers :D
is this cause its public ?
Should i do the UserInputs in the Main function directly ?

Comment: Try `float input = float.Parse(usrInput);`. `Parse` is a static method and can only be statically invoked from the type not from an instance.

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
input = float.Parse(usrInput);
```

instead of

```
input.Parse(usrInput);
```

Refer to [How to convert a string to a number (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-number).